# What is the meaning of "Jigolo har Megiddo"?

Tags: meaning

I tried to search and translate the words of this song title by Ghost, "Jigolo har Megiddo."

I couldn’t find anything, I couldn’t even figure out the language, I guess Italian?! What is the meaning of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "jigolo" or gigolo is a heterosexual male prostitute and Megiddo is an ancient city (more famous under its Greek name, Armageddon), where the Book of Revelations prophesies a world-ending battle.  So the name is basically "The Male Prostitute of the Apocalypse," which fits the lyrics.

https://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107859458675/